# How do I connect to neo4j port from AWS Lightsail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to access the neo4j port from public internet on AWS lightsail. I have configured the filewall but sill not able to do it.

[image]

I am running neo4j in a docker container like

```html
$ sudo docker run     --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 --publish=7473:7473  --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data  --volume=$HOME/neo
[1] 1542
$ Starting Neo4j.
2017-10-06 01:43:42.192+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.0.11 ========
2017-10-06 01:43:42.229+0000 INFO  No SSL certificate found, generating a self-signed certificate..
2017-10-06 01:43:42.793+0000 INFO  Starting...
2017-10-06 01:43:43.454+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
2017-10-06 01:43:46.135+0000 INFO  Started.
2017-10-06 01:43:47.098+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://0.0.0.0:7474/
```

I am not able to connect to it from the browser.
as http::7474 ?

Comment: Welcome on SO! This question my be better suited for one of the other Stack-sites. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141942/best-stack-exchange-site-for-asking-about-amazon-aws

Comment: I think this question belongs to [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: If you to an nmap -p 7474 <ip of server> from your client machine ... does it show the port as OPEN (FILTERED or CLOSED indicate a firewall) ?

Comment: @Younus you will need to map the host (Lightsail instance) port to the port of the running container. Think of it like a switch board. A call is coming into the machine instance but it does not know where to send the request to get processed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure remote access.

https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-enable-remote-https-access-with-neo4j-30x/

Edit your conf file:
`org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0`